# Firebase Cloud Messaging sound error

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a notification using firebase api and the notification is sent successfully if I only have "title" and "body" in the notification JSON object. However, if I add "sound":"default" to the notification object, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), I get the following error:

"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"sound\" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field."

My JSON object is as follows:

```
{"message":{"token": token, "notification":{"title":"Test", "body":"Test message from server", "sound":"default"}}}
```

Answer (score 40):

The appearance of `message` in your JSON indicates you are using the [HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages).  The documentation you linked is for the legacy API.

The HTTP v1 API JSON to send a notification with sound for Android and iOS devices should be:

```
{
    "message": {
        "token": "your-token-value",
        "notification": {
            "title": "Test",
            "body": "Test message from server"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "sound": "default"
            }
        },
        "apns": {
            "payload": {
                "aps": {
                    "sound": "default"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tha same problem and if I use this structure I got this error.
**Payload of Apple Push Notification Service must contain an [aps] key.**

Comment: @cicaletto79:  I updated my answer after reviewing [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#apns_specific_fields).